# Get hash of different chunk (into Service Worker) using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, service-worker

I have a web app using a Service Worker to prefetch and cache all assets. So I need a cache key that changes when your assets do, like the hash for the chunk with my assets. However, I struggle to get that hash into the template for the Service Worker.

Here is a simplified version of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const extractSW = new ExtractTextPlugin('serviceworker.js');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['./scripts/main.js'],
    serviceworker: ['./templates/serviceworker.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        resource: path.resolve(__dirname, 'templates', 'serviceworker.js'),
        loader: extractSW.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'apply-loader',
              options: {obj: {hash: <hash>}}
            },
            {
              loader: 'underscore-template-loader'
            }
          ] 
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [extractSW, new UglifyJSPlugin()]
};
```

How do I make `<hash>` being the hash of the `main` chunk?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a Webpack plugin that handles all the intricacies of cache versioning for you, like [`WorkboxWebpackPlugin`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/get-started/webpack) (which I work on) or [`offline-plugin`](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin).

You'll end up being able to cache files on a more granular level, for one thing, and only redownload the files that have actually changed (instead of redownloading everything whenever the `main` chunk's hash changes).